# MongoDB + PHP how to select

Tags: php, mongodb

Structure :

Collection : merchant > id, name, country

I want to select all name field from this collection, but all the documentation I read says I must specify the name like :

```
  $name = array('name' => 'test');

  $cursor = $collection->find($name);
```

PS : Something like

> **select name from merchant**

in sql is enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
db.merchant.find({}, {"name": 1});
```

Which would be translated to the following PHP code:

```
$name = array('name' => 1);
```

Hope this would solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing the first optional parameter `query` with the second optional parameter `fields` ...

http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.find.php

`public MongoCursor MongoCollection::find ([ array $query = array() [, array $fields = array() ]] )`

If you pass basically an empty array for your `query` (ala *) and *name* for the `fields` ... that should work.

`$db->collection->find(array(), array("name" => 1));`

This mapping chart might be helpful for you: http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.sqltomongo.php

Comment: This will return _id field, not name :(